# Generating SQL Database on Client PC

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have an application that uses SQL Server and I am working on a setup that should generate the Database on the Client machine from a script.
As a prerequisite for installation I have selected SQL Server Express 2012 and the .Net Framework. 
My question is, will SQL Server Express 2012 be enough to make accessing the database possible on the Client machine? 
Also, will my Code for generating the Database from the script run on another PC, specifically the "Data Source=.\BeneSQL" worries me, since that is "unique" to my PC, or will the script generate that part aswell?

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!CheckDatabaseExist())
            {
                GenerateDatabase();
            }
        }

        private bool CheckDatabaseExist()
        {
            SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\BeneSQL;Initial Catalog=TryingDB;Integrated Security=True");
            try
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();       

                return true;

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
                return false;
            }
        }

        private void GenerateDatabase()
        {
            List<string> cmds = new List<string>();
            if (File.Exists(Application.StartupPath + "\\Skript.sql"))
            {
                TextReader tr = new StreamReader(Application.StartupPath + "\\Skript.sql");
                string line = "";
                string cmd = "";
                while ((line = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (line.Trim().ToUpper() == "GO")
                    {
                        cmds.Add(cmd);
                        cmd = "";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cmd += line + "\r\n";
                    }
                }
                if (cmd.Length > 0)
                {
                    cmds.Add(cmd);
                    cmd = "";
                }
                tr.Close();
            }
            if (cmds.Count > 0)
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
                command.Connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\BeneSQL;Initial Catalog=MASTER;Integrated Security=True");
                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                command.Connection.Open();
                for(int i=0; i<cmds.Count; i++)
                {
                    command.CommandText = cmds[i];
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what instance name will be used for the SQL Server 2012 installation.
If SQL Server is installed on a default instance (.) without name, your code will not work, because it will not be able to connect to the instance .\BeneSQL , because it will not exist.

Otherwise, if SQL Server is installed on an instance named BeneSQL , then your code should work, because it will find the instance.

Comment: I see. Would SQL Server Express 2012 work for this on the Client machine? I am using SQL Server Management Studio on my PC, and I am very new to this, so I dont know what the different versions really do. Express 2012 is listed in the prerequisites in the Setup Project, so I just selected that.

Comment: @BeneTan Your goal seems to be to install all (App+Database) on the client machine. Don't know exactly when installing SQL Server as a prerequisite if it will be installed on a default instance (without name) or if it will ask for the instance name (as the SQL Server Installation process does normally). In case of install it on the default instance, you should change your code to find SQL Server on (.) or (localhost). If the SQL Server installation process as a prerequisite ask you for the instance name, then you can use BeneSQL, and leave your code as is.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see that working for the reasons you suspect.

Try

```
                command.Connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=MASTER;Integrated Security=True");
```

Comment: Does not seem like "localhost"  works. on my machine it doesnt connect

Comment: Are you using a named instance (BeneSQL) rather than a default instance?

Comment: Yes I am. To be completely honest I dont actually know what a default instance is.

Comment: The default instance has no second part to the name so you can access it via `servername` rather than `servername\instancename` which is why I suggested localhost as that should work on any machine with a local default SQL Server instance.

Comment: That sounds like it would solve all my issues. How can I set that up? I have been looking how to add a different instance in SQL Server Management, but i couldn't figure it out.

Comment: I think you have to reinstall SQL Server. Selecting the Default instance, rather than a named instance is done during the set up so look out for it.